# SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 56 invalid identifier

Tags: sql, string, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need small help in resolving error. I have logged in to Snowflake with ACCCOUNTADMIN role (for worksheet as well). I can run query successfully when I don't add WHERE clause. When I add WHERE clause it throws error. Here are both queries.

Success Query:

```
SELECT NAME, CREATED_ON, EMAIL, MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD, EXPIRES_AT, PASSWORD_LAST_SET_TIME 
FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."USERS";
```

Error Query:

```
SELECT NAME, CREATED_ON, EMAIL, MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD, EXPIRES_AT, PASSWORD_LAST_SET_TIME 
FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."USERS" 
WHERE "NAME" = "MYTESTUSER_1";
```

Error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 56 invalid identifier 'MYTESTUSER_1'

There is no issue with `WHERE` clause. Corresponding user is existing. I have check it for a few other users as well. Same error.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In standard SQL, which Snowflake follows in that regard, double quotes stand for identifiers (column names, table names, and so on). In the context of the `where` clause, the database understands `"MYTESTUSER_1"` as the name of a column (which obviously, does not exist), hence the error that you are getting.

You want a literal string, so you need single quotes instead. That is, change:

```
WHERE "NAME" = "MYTESTUSER_1"
```

To:

```
WHERE "NAME" = 'MYTESTUSER_1'
```

Comment: Thank you. That was silly mistake from my side. I oversight to make out from single quote and double quote.